# Windows 環境で AWS KMS のデータキーを復号したい

Tags: windows, コマンドプロンプト, aws-cli

AWS CLIをインストールし、windowsのコマンドプロンプトでCMKからデータキーを作成しました。
"Plaintext"を使用してファイルの暗号化と復号化はできたのですが、"CiphertextBlob"から復号化用のデータを作成できません。正しい方法や必要な設定があれば教えていただきたいです。

１．キー情報表示

```
aws kms generate-data-key --key-id ＜CMKのARN＞ --key-spec AES_256
{
    "CiphertextBlob": "[encrypted-datakey-string]",
    "Plaintext": "[plain-datakey-string]",
    "KeyId": ＜CMKのARN＞
}
```

２．復号化用のデータキーを保存

```
echo [encrypted-datakey-string] > C:\テスト\encrypted-datakey-pre
```

３．データキーの復号
※plain-datakeyと同じものができる想定だが、
InvalidCiphertextExceptionと表示され失敗してしまう。

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob C:\テスト\encrypted-datakey-pre --output text --query Plaintext > C:\テスト\decrypted-datakey-test
An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation:
```